# How to select an answer from a drop down list that contains an apostrophe?

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, webdriver

I got this InvalidSelectorException when I try to select an answer with an apostrophe in it using webdriver (happens in all browsers). I've tried to use the backslash to escape the apostrophe, but I think it's because it's stored in a variable it's not getting escaped:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The xpath expression '//select[@name='titleCode']/option[@value='I'm in college']' cannot be evaluated or does notresult in a WebElement (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 219 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
Session ID: 6efb7eae-3afb-4ab1-948d-146b42d2c96c
Command duration or timeout: 701 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:09:54'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.2.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.6.0_31'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Session ID: 1350062508295
```

Here is the java code. The variables quesiton and answer are string lists from a DB:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='" + question + "']/option[@value='" + answer + "']")).click();
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<select id="select1" class="select" name="titleCode">
<option selected="" value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="I'm in high school">I'm in high school</option>
<option value="I'm in college">I'm in college</option>
</select>
```

Is there a way to escape the apostrophe of a string that is stored in a variable or another way around this or is the apostrophe even the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciative. Thanks!


Bryan

Comment: If you need `answer` to be dynamic, I'd just not use XPath for that part of the query. Get the `<selects> and loop over the answers.

Comment: if it doesn't contain quotes does it work?

Comment: Yeah it works when it doesn't contain quotes. Yeah I guess I could just grab a random value from the list. I'm still curious if there is a way to escape the quotes within a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
    <select id="select1" class="select" name="titleCode">
    <option selected="" value="">Please select...</option>
    <option value="I&#39;m in high school">I&#39;m in high school</option>
    <option value="I&#39;m in college">I&#39;m in college</option>
</select>
```

Between the option tags should not be necessary since they are not posted, but just in case.

I hope this works

Comment: I kind of did the easy way out and did the way that millimoose chose, but this is definitely a way that I have not tried.